# Insert table with fixed width

Tags: tables, width

I want to insert a table into my article. The following code can work.

```
\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{Table 1 Normal function table}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
    & $x<0$     & $x=0$     & $x>0$\\ \hline
$y<0$ & $x^2-y^2$ & $x^2+y^2$ & $x^2-y^2$\\ \hline
$y=0$ & $x+y$     & $x^2-y^2$ & $x^2+y^2$ \\ \hline
$y>0$ & $x^2+y^2$ & $x+y$     & $x^2+y^2$\\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

But I want to fix the table's width, so I changed the fourth line as
`\begin{tabular}{\textwidth}{|c|c|c|c|}`
but it's error, the pdf can't be generated.

Comment: Welcome to the site.  If you indent code blocks by 4 spaces, they will display as code.  Alternately, highlight the block and click on the `{}`icon above the edit box.  For inline code highlighting, enclose the `code` in grave accents.

Comment: It is the `tabular*` environment that allows width specification, not straight `tabular`.

Comment: I have solved my problem using your tips. Thanks a lot